# Tibble reversing coordinates

Tags: r, dplyr, coordinates, transform, tidyverse

I'm trying to do an operation which a prior seem simple but I'm didn't find an explicit solution on the web.

I got this kind of table:

```
tibble(
   block = c(1,1,1,2,2,2),
   tag = letters[1:6],
   start = c(15,54,78,27,45,80),
   end = c(50,80,90,40,76,100),
   direction = c(-1,-1,1,1,1,1),
   anchor = c(FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE)
) -> df1
# A tibble: 6 x 6
  block tag   start   end direction anchor
  <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl> <lgl> 
1     1 a        15    50        -1 FALSE 
2     1 b        54    80        -1 TRUE  
3     1 c        78    90         1 FALSE 
4     2 d        27    40         1 FALSE 
5     2 e        45    76         1 TRUE  
6     2 f        80   100         1 FALSE
```

I got groups in the `block` column and only 1 `anchor` by a group.
Given the `anchor == TRUE`, I need to **invert (`direction * -1`) the coordinates within a block if the anchor direction is `-1` (`direction[anchor] == -1)`**, also need **keep the anchor coordinates (`start` & `end`)** and adjust the other and coordinates of `anchor == FALSE` to keep them crescent but with same scales (length and distance to up and downstream tags).

To simplify, I need to rescale the coordinates if the anchor of the group is `-1`.
That means, if the `anchor == -1` then:

1. `ancho * -1`
2. tag orders must be reverted
3. coordinates will be changed keeping the length of the tags and distance between then the same

Then, the output just need to be something like this:

```
tibble(
  block = c(1,1,1,2,2,2),
  tag = c("c", "b", "a", "d", "e", "f"),
  start = c(44,54,84,27,45,80),
  end = c(56,80,119,40,76,100),
  direction = c(-1,1,1,1,1,1),
  anchor = c(FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE)
) -> df2
# A tibble: 6 x 6
  block tag   start   end direction anchor
  <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl> <lgl> 
1     1 c        44    56        -1 FALSE 
2     1 b        54    80         1 TRUE  
3     1 a        84   119         1 FALSE 
4     2 d        27    40         1 FALSE 
5     2 e        45    76         1 TRUE  
6     2 f        80   100         1 FALSE
```

As you may see below, the lengths and the pair distances keep the same:

```
df1 %>% 
  group_by(block) %>% 
  mutate(
    TagDistance = lead(start) - end,
    len = end - start
  )
# A tibble: 6 x 8
# Groups:   block [2]
  block tag   start   end direction anchor TagDistance   len
  <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl> <lgl>        <dbl> <dbl>
1     1 a        15    50        -1 FALSE            4    35
2     1 b        54    80        -1 TRUE            -2    26
3     1 c        78    90         1 FALSE           NA    12
4     2 d        27    40         1 FALSE            5    13
5     2 e        45    76         1 TRUE             4    31
6     2 f        80   100         1 FALSE           NA    20



df2 %>% 
  group_by(block) %>% 
  mutate(
    TagDistance = lead(start) - end,
    len = end - start
  )
# A tibble: 6 x 8
# Groups:   block [2]
  block tag   start   end direction anchor TagDistance   len
  <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl> <lgl>        <dbl> <dbl>
1     1 c        44    56        -1 FALSE           -2    12
2     1 b        54    80         1 TRUE             4    26
3     1 a        84   119         1 FALSE           NA    35
4     2 d        27    40         1 FALSE            5    13
5     2 e        45    76         1 TRUE             4    31
6     2 f        80   100         1 FALSE           NA    20
```

A graphical representation is this:

```
library(ggplot2)   
library(gggenes)   
df1 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(xmin = start, xmax = end, y = as.factor(block), forward = direction, fill = anchor)) +
  geom_gene_arrow() +
  geom_gene_label(aes(label = tag)) +
  theme_genes() 
#
df2 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(xmin = start, xmax = end, y = as.factor(block), forward = direction, fill = anchor)) +
  geom_gene_arrow() +
  geom_gene_label(aes(label = tag)) +
  theme_genes()
```

[image: DF1]
[image: DF2]

Thanks in advance

Comment: what does the `ld` stand for?

Comment: If you only need the _length_, regardless of the direction, running `mutate(your_data, len = abs(end - start))` is enough. Not sure if I got your problem though

Comment: @lcgodoy `ld` is the distance between the lag and lead `tag`

Comment: I changed to `TagDistance` to be more explicit. In sense, it is the distance between two near tags within the same group (e.g. `a` to `b`, `b` to `c`, ....)

Comment: It is not clear to me how are you getting new numbers in `start` and `end`  columns. Also how are values in `direction` column changed.

Comment: There is just one `anchor == TRUE` by block. The `anchor == TRUE` aways must keep the start & end coordinates, but if the anchor direction is `-1` then all block must change the direction. It is a 1D vector, like genes in DNA, then the relative positions like the length of each tag (or gene) and the distance to the up or downstream tags also must keep the same. I'll include a grafical representation to explain.

Comment: @RonakShah I added details and a graphical representation to try to be as clear as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved, quite dumb, probably there is some better solution?

```
tibble(
  block = c(1,1,1,2,2,2),
  tag = letters[1:6],
  start = c(15,54,78,27,45,80),
  end = c(50,80,90,40,76,100),
  direction = c(-1,-1,1,1,1,1),
  anchor = c(FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE)
) -> a
a
# A tibble: 6 x 6
  block tag   start   end direction anchor
  <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl> <lgl> 
1     1 a        15    50        -1 FALSE 
2     1 b        54    80        -1 TRUE  
3     1 c        78    90         1 FALSE 
4     2 d        27    40         1 FALSE 
5     2 e        45    76         1 TRUE  
6     2 f        80   100         1 FALSE
```

Then I grouped by `block` and perform a lot of arithmetic operations up a heuristic like:

```
a %>% 
  group_by(block) %>% 
  mutate(
    anchor_direction = direction[anchor],
    position_relative_to_anchor = case_when(
      anchor ~ NA_character_,
      (start < start[anchor]) | (start == start[anchor] && end < end[anchor]) ~ "upstream",
      start > start[anchor] ~ "downstream"
    ),
    TagDistance = if_else(
      position_relative_to_anchor == "upstream",
      start[anchor] - end,
      start - end[anchor]
    ),
    length = end - start,
    newstart = case_when(
      anchor ~ start,
      anchor_direction == 1 ~ start,
      position_relative_to_anchor == "upstream" ~ end[anchor] + TagDistance,
      position_relative_to_anchor == "downstream" ~ start[anchor] - TagDistance
    ),
    newend = case_when(
      anchor ~ end,
      anchor_direction == 1 ~ end,
      position_relative_to_anchor == "upstream" ~ newstart + length,
      position_relative_to_anchor == "downstream" ~ newstart - length
    ),
    start = case_when(
      anchor ~ start,
      anchor_direction == 1 ~ start,
      position_relative_to_anchor == "upstream" ~ newstart,
      position_relative_to_anchor == "downstream" ~ newend
    ),
    end = case_when(
      anchor ~ end,
      anchor_direction == 1 ~ end,
      position_relative_to_anchor == "upstream"    ~ newend,
      position_relative_to_anchor == "downstream"  ~ newstart
    )
  ) %>% 
  arrange(block,start,end) %>% 
  mutate(
    direction = direction * anchor_direction
  ) %>% 
  select(
    -c(
      anchor_direction,
      position_relative_to_anchor, 
      TagDistance,
      length,
      newstart,
      newend
    )
  ) -> a
a
# A tibble: 6 x 6
# Groups:   block [2]
  block tag   start   end direction anchor
  <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl> <lgl> 
1     1 c        44    56        -1 FALSE 
2     1 b        54    80         1 TRUE  
3     1 a        84   119         1 FALSE 
4     2 d        27    40         1 FALSE 
5     2 e        45    76         1 TRUE  
6     2 f        80   100         1 FALSE
```

Finally, I compared with the expected result:

```
tibble(
  block = c(1,1,1,2,2,2),
  tag = c("c", "b", "a", "d", "e", "f"),
  start = c(44,54,84,27,45,80),
  end = c(56,80,119,40,76,100),
  direction = c(-1,1,1,1,1,1),
  anchor = c(FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE)
) -> b
setdiff(a, b)
# A tibble: 0 x 6
# Groups:   block [0]
# … with 6 variables: block <dbl>, tag <chr>, start <dbl>, end <dbl>, direction <dbl>, anchor <lgl>
```

Any better solution is welcome.